# Asking for a reference which proves analytic continuation of Hypergeometric Function

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, hypergeometric-function, analytic-continuation

I am self studying a research paper in analytic number theory  and it requires analyticity of Hypergeometric Function .

> I searched google but i couldnot found anything precize on how to prove analytic continuation of this function .
>   Can someone please suggest some reference book or article for it .

Comment: why i am getting downvotes ? can somebody please explain what is mistake in the question . What more I need to write ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hypergeometric series satisfies (in the region where it converges) a homogeneous linear differential equation with polynomial coefficients.  In a neighbourhood of any line segment in the complex plane that avoids the singularities, this will have analytic solutions.

Comment: where can i find a proof of your statement?

Comment: can you please look at this question related to hypergeometric function if you have some spare time https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523183/an-argument-in-paper-of-wadim-zudilin-irrationality-of-values-of-riemann-zeta-f